# Yamaha FZS 600 Faser - Losing a cylinder when hot

Tags: engine, motorcycle, misfire, yamaha, cylinder

I recently bought a 1999 Yamaha FZS 600 Fazer. It was absolutely fine on the test ride. Did a couple of other short rides (about 20 mins), also fine. Then today after about 15 mins I lose a cylinder. It feels like it just stopped firing.

I got to my destination and left it for a little while. Then after 10-15 mins started the bike. It felt fine. Then after a min or so the cylinder goes again and I'm back to riding a triple (or a twin, but I'm pretty sure it's just one that went). It feels like it comes back when revving really high, but splutters lower in the rev range.

It was serviced before I purchased it, so I'm assuming the spark plugs are fine.

I have a few questions:

1. Does anyone have any ideas on what  might be wrong, or suggestions
   on what I could check?
2. How do I find out which cylinder isn't firing?
3. The previous owner fitted a scottoiler which they removed before selling. Looks like the vacuum spigot is on the throttle body. Could that cause a problem if it wasn't replaced properly?

Comment: Maybe bad spark plugs?

Comment: @Moab sparks are new so should be fine. Will double check them though.

Comment: Perhaps one of the carbs has an iffy jet. I had a 4-carb GPZ-550 which exhibited something like that, but it was cured by a 10-mile revvy whack.

Comment: You can find out which cylinder it is by pulling off one spark plug lead at a time (wear insulating gloves). Although it might be carburation, the one that makes least difference is the one with a problem.

Comment: Because the fault is caused by heat, I'd suspect some part of the ignition system: the coil that drives the failing cylinder, or the HT wires to the plug, or something similar.